# Multiplication of NDArray in oct file

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, octave, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to convert an .m file to an .oct file in Octave and part of the .m file code is:-

```
for hh = 1 : nt      
bi_star = bi_star + A( : , : , hh ) * data( : , : , hh + 1 )' ;
end
```

where both "A" and "data" are of NDArray type. I have tried to extract the values from the NDArrays by using something like

```
A.extract( 0 , 0 , num_dims-1 , num_dims-1 , hh ) ;
```

but get the error message

```
error: ‘class NDArray’ has no member named ‘extract’
```

when compiling. The only other way I can think of doing this at the moment is to put nested loops within the hh loop to loop over both "A" and "data" to fill in intermediate calculation matrices and do the matrix multiplications and additions using these intermediate matrices. However, this seems to be a very long winded way of doing things. Is there a more efficient way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Crossposting here http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/Multiplication-of-NDArray-in-oct-file-td4669676.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Andy's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29572075/how-do-you-create-an-arrayoctave-idx-type-in-an-oct-file) and its included link to the Octave sources page, I have been able to figure out that I simply need to use:

```
A.page ( hh )
```

to accomplish what I what.

Thanks Andy!